Why are Conv1D layers used in time series predictions with LSTM if it takes in future data?
It seems as though may tutorials are using Conv1D layers along with LSTM layers in Keras. However, the steps in the Conv1D are changed, and just so happen to align with the timesteps in LSTM. This means that the kernel of the Conv1D is accessing data from around the current time, aka. looking in the future.
LSTM INPUT: batch_size, timesteps, features
CONV 1D Input: batch_size, steps, channels
CONV 1D Output: batch_size, new_steps, channels
*since the Conv1D has new_steps in the shape, I'm assuming that it looks over the channels in the steps.
Why are you able to use the Conv1D with LSTM if it looks into the future with the kernel? Is there a different way to use it or does it not actually look at the timesteps?
First, I createed a model with Conv1D and LSTM, with the LSTM having return_sequences = True and the Conv1D having padding = 'same'.
            self.model.add(Input(shape = (None, len(self.data.columns) - 1)))
            self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
            self.model.add
            (RNN(StackedRNNCells(
            [
                LSTMCell(256),
                LSTMCell(256),
            ],
            ), return_sequences = True)
            )
            self.model.add(GaussianDropout(0.3, 1))
            self.model.add(Dense(64, activation = leaky_relu))
            self.model.add(Conv1D(64, 16, activation = tanh, padding = 'same'))
            self.model.add(Dense(64, activation = leaky_relu))
            self.model.add(Dense(1, activation = sigmoid))

It predicted astonishingly well, which is why I am asking here. Then, I tried channels_first but it didn't allow me since I had a variable length time series, with an input size of None. I have found that there is a Conv1DLSTM layer which combines the 2, but I am unsure what the extra rows in the input_shape is for, making it a 4d input as opposed to a 3d input.
I also looked at this Stack and it says that the axis that Conv1D works on is the time steps.
